# How to make print of web page particular area contains with charts?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, browser, printing, charts

I have a problem with printing a chart.

I made a web page contains with some number of controls and one chart, using Microsoft chart control. The issue currently is affecting me in both IE 8 and Firefox 9.0.1

When I made a print by using JavaScript then it prints all controls which are contained in div, but the chart control is not showing on the print preview page which is in same div.

Comment: Can you be more precise & share what have coded for printing charts? Also are you using Microsoft Chart Controls or something 3rd Party charting tool?

Comment: Construct a page that includes chart only and at the end of page add JavaScript print() and close() method.

Comment: Who *upvotes* a question like this without waiting for it to get improved? If you want to be nice to the OP, give helpful tips on how to improve the question.

Comment: In what browser are you trying to print it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) you can try following code for printing :

```
public void PrintWebControl(Control ctrl, string Script)    
{
    StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter(); 
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

    if (ctrl is WebControl)    
    {
      Unit w = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage);
      ((WebControl)ctrl).Width = w;
    }

    Page pg = new Page();
    pg.EnableEventValidation =false;

    if (Script != string.Empty)    
    {
      pg.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(pg.GetType(), "PrintJavaScript", Script);
    }

    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();

    pg.Controls.Add(frm);

    frm.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

    frm.Controls.Add(ctrl);

    pg.DesignerInitialize();

    pg.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

    string strHTML = stringWrite.ToString();

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTML);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>window.print();</script>");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

}
```

Calling :

```
PrintWebControl(Panel1);
```

gets you the print of the required chart.

Comment: But the thing is that he's trying to print a page where such a control is embedded. I think his question is why it doesn't show up.

Comment: What is contents of **Script** parameter?